# Density Estimation and Data Normalization

Tags: distributions, data-mining, normalization, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Is there any problem to first normalize data (for example, min-max one) then use kernel density estimation to get pdf of each sample?

Thanks.

Comment: Mathematically not, numerically probably not

Comment: Thanks. My problem is outlier detection and this works for me but when I don't normalize and get pdf, it doesn't work. I just wanted to make sure this procedure is OK. Also what about standardizing data using z-score before getting the pdf? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the structure of the data remains unchanged, it doesn't make a difference. I've tried out a small example to verify it, Matlab code can be found below.
You can see that the structure in the scatter plots is the same. The differences between the density plots are likely due to the differences in bandwidth, as they are estimated for all three samples separately. Nonetheless, you can see that there are no notable differences in structure.

### Plot

[image: Plot produced by the code example. It shows 3 scatter plots in the top row and 3 density plots in the bottom row, the columns corresponding to the original data, 0-1 normalized data and the z-score standardized data]

### Code

```
rng(5)
colormap jet
% % original data
X1 = [normrnd(2,1,50,1),normrnd(6,4,50,1)];
X2 = [normrnd(4,2,70,1),normrnd(10,3,70,1)];
X=[X1;X2];
subplot(2,3,1)
scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2))
title('Scatter of original data')
xlim([min(X(:,1)),max(X(:,1))])
ylim([min(X(:,2)),max(X(:,2))])
gridx1 = linspace(min(X(:,1)),max(X(:,1)),100);
gridx2 = linspace(min(X(:,2)),max(X(:,2)),100);
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(gridx1, gridx2);
x1 = x1(:);
x2 = x2(:);
xi = [x1 x2];
subplot(2,3,4)
ksdensity(X,xi,'PlotFcn','contour');
title('Kernel density estimate on original data')
colorbar()

% % normalized to 0-1
X_zo(:,1) = (X(:,1)-min(X(:,1)))/(max(X(:,1))-min(X(:,1)));
X_zo(:,2) = (X(:,2)-min(X(:,2)))/(max(X(:,2))-min(X(:,2)));
subplot(2,3,2)
scatter(X_zo(:,1),X_zo(:,2))
title('Scatter of data normalized to 0-1')
xlim([min(X_zo(:,1)),max(X_zo(:,1))])
ylim([min(X_zo(:,2)),max(X_zo(:,2))])
gridx1 = linspace(min(X_zo(:,1)),max(X_zo(:,1)),100);
gridx2 = linspace(min(X_zo(:,2)),max(X_zo(:,2)),100);
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(gridx1, gridx2);
x1 = x1(:);
x2 = x2(:);
xi = [x1 x2];
subplot(2,3,5)
ksdensity(X_zo,xi,'PlotFcn','contour');
title('Kernel density estimate on 0-1 normalized data')
colorbar()

% % standardized z-score
X_s = zscore(X);
subplot(2,3,3)
scatter(X_s(:,1),X_s(:,2))
title('Scatter of standardized data')
xlim([min(X_s(:,1)),max(X_s(:,1))])
ylim([min(X_s(:,2)),max(X_s(:,2))])
gridx1 = linspace(min(X_s(:,1)),max(X_s(:,1)),100);
gridx2 = linspace(min(X_s(:,2)),max(X_s(:,2)),100);
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(gridx1, gridx2);
x1 = x1(:);
x2 = x2(:);
xi = [x1 x2];
subplot(2,3,6)
ksdensity(X_s,xi,'PlotFcn','contour');
title('Kernel density estimate on standardized data')
colorbar()
```

Comment: Thanks. Please let me have an aside question. Could, you, please, introduce an applied machine learning and deep learning book with python?

Comment: Please consider [searching the site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5breferences%5d%20python) for this