# I have difficulties to understand the input normalization - density estimation in the same context in ML or DL

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normalization, density-estimation

I know (by experimenting with different ML and DL algorithms) that input normalization helps to improve the performance of the model. When we do normalization in training, with the same mean and variance, we need to normalize our test set to be consistent. I understand that when some of our features range between for ex. -1,+1 and some other let's say +10000,+1000000, input normalization helps the model to give equal importance to each feature. If not, it can maybe discard features in range -1,+1 and focus only on features that range in very large values. This is what I learned and what makes sense to me.

However, for density estimation, for example, our aim is to find for a given data (say with m example and 2 feature) our aim is to understand what is the distribution of feature 1 (mean1 and variance1) and of feature 2 (mean2 and variance2). But if we normalize our input columns to 0 mean 1 variance. How we can find these distributions. I can not make a connection between these two: input normalization and density estimation.

It seems to me that we are losing the information needed to do the density estimation. I experimented that it does not hurt the density estimation, I know. But I can not understand how this can be possible to not hurt. I am not able to clarify this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Density Estimation and Data Normalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406184/density-estimation-and-data-normalization)

Comment: It is about the same topic but my question is not the same as asked there. I experimented with my data and I know that it works, does not hurt density estimation. But the thing that I can not clearly understand is that, why?

Comment: It is true the duplicate does not explain why.  (IMHO, it doesn't have a good answer in that respect.)  But all we're talking about here is the choice of which units to use for analyzing data, such as grams or pounds.  It doesn't matter.  And all that normalization does is change the units.  If you forget what your unit of measurement is, then indeed you have lost information.  The solution is to remember it!  keep a record of the change of origin and scale you used and all will be fine.

Comment: I read again but I do not understand your explanation.. Particularly relation of this "The solution is to remember it! keep a record of the change of origin and scale you used and all will be fine." and that "for density estimation, our aim is to find for a given data (say with m examples and 2 features) our aim is to find the distribution of feature 1 (mean1 and var1) and of feature 2 (mean2 and var2). If we normalize our input columns to 0 mean, 1 variance how we can find these distributions?" @whuber

Comment: You can view this is as a direct application of the [quantity calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity_calculus).